# Is it haram to say I don't believe in something about a disputed matter?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, shirk, hanafi, belief

Assalamualaikum, I actually searched on google whether eating lobster is halal or haram? I found that hanafi school calls eating lobster haram, I live in India where mostly everyone goes with hanafi way, but I actually wanted to eat a lobster and I said in my mind I don't believe in it but I found out that only hanafi calls eating lobster haram. Will this be shirk as saying something you don't believe in it haram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True believers always consider themselves bound by the obligations of faith. Whether these obligations are in their personal interest or not in accordance with their personal interests, they obey God's command and submit to it.
In verse 91 of Surah Al-Hijr, he speaks of people who act only on parts of the Qur'an that the interpretation of the Qur'an is interesting in this regard ».
Some Muslims do not view religious responsibilities as a binding obligation. Rather, they adhere to those commitments to the extent that it is compatible with their personal interests, and otherwise, with negligence and carelessness, they set them aside. The Qur'anic culture explicitly declares such people - who may have stored a heart of faith for the days of distress in the corners of the heart - to be unbelievers and unbelievers, and considers God's promises to the believers to be those who adhere to them at all times. And are committed to the duties of religion.

The religion of the Imams is the condition for making fish permissible to have scales, and it is forbidden to eat anything in the sea except fish and shrimp.
In the Hanafi religion, except for fish and shrimp, everything in the sea is forbidden.
In the Maliki religion, all sea creatures are lawful; Except for hounds and guinea pigs, which are considered abominable.
In the Shafi'i and Hanbali religions, all kinds of sea fish and shrimp are considered halal; But for them, the blue frog is forbidden.
Imami and Hanafi religions have considered cultivation as a condition for fish, but other religions have not considered it as a condition and eating dead fish is permissible and lawful.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can separate this issue in multiple parts ;

Disbeliving in something to be haram

Is eating lobster haram;

"Abu Huraira reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, was asked about sea water and he said, “Its water is purifying for ablution, and its dead animals are lawful to eat.”
Source: Sunan al-Tirmidhī 69"

Basically eating any sea only food is halal ;
[The sheikh explains; 00:33 sec](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeipAxITSVQ)  The title is octopus but he'll say every sea animal is halal

Also animals that lives on both land & sea are maybe haram;

Also about disbeliving in a matter that is clear; because madhabs are opinions of people and you should try your best to follow the truth , not madhab;

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/115125/ruling-on-one-who-rejects-a-saheeh-hadith

cuz if you disbelive in a matter that is clear , like in the quran or clear sahih hadith , that is problematic ; but a matter where there is no clear indications , you should try to know what's halal;

But if you know the truth , if you belive something to be true ,then you should follow ; like hijab &  niqab difference

If you're a layman it's okay to follow a madhab ,; but don't pick and choose things from madhab; [watch this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-gTmqqW5Os&t=213s) few mins

Comment: I think I've already asked you to distinguish your own words from quotes. Please act upon this inquiry.

Comment: Why for nothing downvote